# Proximal Operator of Scaled Function

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, proximal-operators

The proximal operator of a function is

$$\text{prox}_f(x) = \text{argmin}_u f(u) + \frac{1}{2}\|u-x\|_2^2.$$

Suppose I have the function that is $\text{prox}_f$.  I would like a simple expression for $\text{prox}_{\lambda f}$ where $\lambda$ is a scalar.  That is, I would like the proximal operator of the scaled function given the proximal operator of the function itself.

Does such an expression exist?

Comment: I believe $\text{prox}_{\lambda f}=[\lambda {\text{prox}_f}^{-1}+(1-\lambda)I]^{-1}$ holds when that expression is defined, based on taking stationary points. I can't offer good proof.

Comment: @nathan.j.mcdougall Do you have a source for this?

Comment: No source, but: consider the particular case of a differentiable $f$. Then a necessary condition is that at the stationary point for the minimum,
$$\nabla f({\text{prox}}_{f}(x))+{\text{prox}}_{f}(x)-x=0.$$
From which we get $(\nabla f+I)\,\circ\,\text{prox}_f=I$, so that when it exists, $\text{prox}_f^{-1}=\nabla f+I$. Likewise, $\text{prox}_{\lambda f}^{-1}=\lambda\nabla f+I$. We can eliminate the derivative thus: $\nabla f = \text{prox}_{f}^{-1}-I=\frac{1}{\lambda}(\text{prox}_{\lambda f}^{-1}-I)$. Rearranging gives my result. That's just differentiable $f$, though. Be rightly skeptical.

Comment: It should be reasonably straightforward to show that $\text{prox}_{f}$ is surjective and strictly increasing for continuous $f$, so that $\text{prox}_{f}$ is invertible and the expression is defined in that case (continuous $f$)

Comment: Can you give an example where this would be relevant? I can't imagine a case where compute $\text{prox}_{f}(x)$ is easier than computing $\text{prox}_{\lambda f}(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

If $\lambda$ is positive and $f$ is convex, proper, and lower-semicontinuous, you can guarantee $\text{prox}_{\lambda f}$ is uniquely-defined. The scalar term usually appears explicitly in the formula for $\text{prox}_{\gamma f}$ e.g. see http://proximity-operator.net/index.html.
In the differentiable case, $\text{prox}_{\gamma f} = x - \gamma \nabla f(x) + o(\gamma)$ as $\gamma \downarrow 0$.
In general, $x = \text{prox}_{\gamma f}x + \gamma \text{prox}_{\gamma^{-1}f^*}(\gamma^{-1}x)$
where $f^*$ is the Fenchel-Legendre conjugate of $f$.

For more references, check Bauschke & Combettes' 2017 book, Section 23.3 on Resolvents (which are generalized proxes). You get results like:

$(\forall \rho \in \mathbb{R} \setminus\{0\}) \quad \text{prox}_{f}x = \rho^{-1}\text{prox}_{\rho^2 f}(\rho x)$